# Gmail Change Account

Tags: pokemon-go

Does anyone knows how to change the gmail account used for Pokémon Go? I created a Pokémon account with my friends gmail account. How can I change it to my own gmail account?

Comment: Not possible for yet, no feature added right now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I use another google account on my phone for Pokémon Go?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274499/why-cant-i-use-another-google-account-on-my-phone-for-pok%c3%a9mon-go)

Comment: That is not a duplicate, because OP does not ask how to log into a different account (with different progress/pokemon/etc), but instead how to move their data to a different google account.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently (15 August 2016) no option to change the google account associated with the Pokemon GO account you are currently playing on.

You could log out and create a new account with your own google account, but you will not have access to the pokemon, items, achievements or experience you already have collected.